# JOGL Navigate Scene with keyboard

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, jogl

I have a program written in Java using JOGL with which you can draw lines with mouse. I now need to be able to navigate within the environment using the keyboard.

The game class code is [here](http://www.shalomplace.co.uk/GameClient.java);

I have done this kind of thing with Java3D before in which you simply call the KeyNav class ad go from there but I can't seem to find the right functionality in JOGL. Any code, tutorials of information much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a project I created. In the example implementation is a small class called Input.java. Just pass your gLAutoDrawable instance in the constructor and it should work.
[Link](https://github.com/iuiz/VolumeShadow/tree/master/VolumeShadow/src/org/volumeshadow/exampleImplementation)

edit:
Oh, and you need to start the thread. :)